# Get Database's Tables

Tags: c#, oracle, ms-access, .net-3.5

I want to write a query to get the names of tables of a specific database, but I don't know how can write it.

I want to execute this query for MS Access 2007 and Oracle 11g.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a database abstraction layer, like the JDBC or perl's DBI?  Many such frameworks have methods to enumerate a database's catalogs, schema and objects (tables, views, etc.), which methods are implemented by specific drivers.

Comment: I think he just means a query to get list of the tables back.

Comment: @AJ, right.  This functionality already exists without the coder having to worry about this or that version of this or that RDBMS (e.g., $dbh->tables() under the DBI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want raw, direct queries:

For Oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM user_tables
```

For MS Access:

```
SELECT * FROM  MSysObjects  WHERE [Type] In (1, 4, 6)
```

(sorting and advanced filtering omitted for brevity.)

Comment: Depending on context, you may get a permissions error on the MS Access query.